# JS Countdown not compatible with jQuery 1.10.2

Tags: javascript

So, my countdown script is for some reason not compatible with my code.
Im trying to make it countdown to a specific time each day, but my web store is limited to only use jquery 1.x with all my other plugins so no other jquery version can be used.
https://jsfiddle.net/nskhbL12/

```
<script>
    window.onload = date;

    function ShowTime() {
       var now = new Date();
       var hrs = 20-now.getHours();
       var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
       var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
       timeLeft = "" +hrs+' t : '+mins+' m : '+secs+' s';
       $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
    }

    var countdown;
    function StopTime() {
        clearInterval(countdown);
    }

    setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
</script>
<span id="date">Order before <span id="countdown"></span> and receive your package tomorrow!</span>
```

Comment: Seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/eauksku8/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because jQuery is not involved.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio you are using v1.9.1. Toni jQuery is used to write HTML text inside '#countdown'.

Comment: It does not work on my local pc using a HTML file.

Comment: I already voted to close for another reason, but this is related - [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: Check this fiddle:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nskhbL12/

Comment: @ThomasBangThomasGaming - It work with v2.2.0 https://jsfiddle.net/nskhbL12/4/

Comment: The website is running on jQuery ver. 1.x. And thats why i included the jQuery tag, because it should only run on ver 1.x, because my store plugins are not compatible with 2.x or 3.x

Comment: @ThomasBangThomasGaming Also with 1.9.1 https://jsfiddle.net/nskhbL12/5/

Comment: I meant jQuery 1.10.2. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @ThomasBangThomasGaming Before your question is closed, DEBUG it - Check your console for errors and report back

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
jQuery(function($) {
    setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
});
```

Or use something like

`$ = jQuery;`